# "UDP datagrams only" socket in C

Tags: c, linux, network-programming

In Linux, Ubuntu 14.04:
I'm writing a code that implements socket to send pure UDP datagrams which includes UDP header+payload, without any part of IP header.

I have created the socket

```
sokt_fd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP)
```

Also, I have prepared the UDP header.

1. I want to leave the IP encapsulation process to the kernel.
2. I want to send the datagram over any available IP interface. (I do not want to specify the source IP, and also leave this task to the kernel).
3. Do I need to specify the destination IP address before sending the datagram.
4. I must use "sendto()" command to send the datagram; how I must fill the "sockaddr" data structure?

   ```
   #include <netinet/in.h>
   struct sockaddr
   {
       unsigned short    sa_family;// address family, AF_xxx
       char              sa_data[14];// 14 bytes of protocol address
   };
   ```

Comment: According to Stevens _UNIX Network Programming_, `IPPROTO_UDP` cannot be used with `SOCK_RAW`. If you want to create your own UDP packets and let the kernel encapsulate them within IP packets, then you should use `IPPROTO_RAW` with `SOCK_RAW`.

Comment: can I creat the socket like this:                 sokt_fd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);   ??

Comment: Yes. That will create a connectionless UDP socket that is not bound to a local address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the `sockaddr` structure. Use `sockaddr_in` instead and cast it when you have to pass a `sockaddr*` to a function.

```
struct sockaddr_in myaddr;
int s;

myaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
myaddr.sin_port = htons(3490);
inet_aton("63.161.169.137", &myaddr.sin_addr.s_addr);

s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)myaddr, sizeof(myaddr));
```

The socket API is designed for different addressing families, others are Infrared and Bluetooth. Since AF_INET is only one of the families the API functions use the general `sockaddr` type in the parameters.

Comment: Why? in the man page of sendto, they used the sokaddr structure

Comment: I have found some code examples used the sockaddr_in , and then cast it, but I do not know why.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice explanation of this in Chapter 3, "Sockets Introduction" in the well-known book **Unix Network Programming, The Sockets Networking API** (Volume 1) by Richard Stevens et. al.  Let me quote:

> Most socket functions require a pointer to a socket address structure
>   as an argument.  Each supported protocol suite defines its own socket
>   address structure.  The names of these structures begin with
>   sockaddr_ and end with a unique suffix for each protocol suite.

For the IP (Internet protocol) suite, the structure is `sockaddr_in` so it follows that since your example is specifying the AF_INET address family when you created the socket that you would use the more specific sockaddr_in structure instead of the more generic sockaddr.  The socket API, as a matter of efficiency uses the more generic sockaddr pointer in the signature prototype.

With regard to using `send()` versus `sendto()`, I have found that `sendto()` is used more commonly with UDP and `send()` with TCP sockets.  Therefore, to answer your question in #3 above, with UDP you don't have to specify the destination address up front, but instead it is supplied as an argument to `sendto()`.

For a given `udp_datagram` and `datagram_length`, your code might look something like this:

```
uint32_t       address = inet_addr("1.2.3.4");   // can also provide hostname here
uint16_t       port    = 27890;
sockaddr_in_t  dest_addr;
memset(*dest_addr, 0, sizeof(dest_addr));

dest_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
dest_addr.sin_port   = htons(port);
dest_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(address);

sendto(socket_fd, 
       (const char*)upd_datagram, 
       datagram_length,
       0,
       reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_t*>(&dest_addr),
       sizeof(dest_addr));
```

Answer (score 0):

The address API really wanted to be object-oriented, but had to deal with the fact that C isn't an OO language. `sockaddr` can be seen as the "base class" and the parameter type that bind, connect, sendto, recvfrom, etc. use when they need an address. However, you must provide a "subclassed" address matching the *socket domain* that you're using. This is because Berkeley sockets can be used for a wide and extensible range of protocols. IPv4 and IPv6 are the most typical, but UNIX-based installs also support sockets as filesystem objects ("addressed" by path), and, for instance, a hypervisor driver can install support for special inter-VM or guest-to-host sockets. See [`man 7 socket`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) for an overview.

If you use IPv4, you need to use `sockaddr_in`. If you use IPv6, you need to use `sockaddr_in6`. In both cases, you need to cast your pointer to a `sockaddr*`.

To fill in a `sockaddr_in`, you need to do something like this:

```
struct sockaddr_in inet_addr;
inet_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
inet_addr.sin_port = htons(port);
inet_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(ip_address_as_number);
struct sockaddr* addr = (struct sockaddr*)&inet_addr;
```

`htons` and `htonl` stand for "host to network (short)" and "host to network (long)", respectively. You need this because there was a time at which network drivers were too dumb to abstract away the machine's endianness and we can't go back in time to fix them. (The network byte order is big endian.)